# try except versus try finally in Delphi

Tags: delphi, lazarus, fpc

Many things have be mentioned for nested exception handling in Delphi or fpc. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155944/c-java-try-finally-catch-equivalent-construct-in-delphi) for example. My question, that maybe solves the need for nested `try...` blocks, is **if there is an actual difference between the following 2 versions of code**, I don't see any *except* if an undefined behavior or something occurs after `expect` or `finally`...

```
try
    StrToInt('AA');
finally
    writeln('I absolutely need this');
end;
writeln('and this');
```

and...

```
try
  StrToInt('AA');
except
end;
writeln('I absolutely need this');
writeln('and this');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is a difference. Huge one.

If there is no exception in `try` block then both versions will execute all code, but if there is an exception behavior differs.

In first version of your code, anything after `finally` block will not be executed and exception will be propagated to the next level.

```
try
    StrToInt('AA'); // if this code throws exception and it will
finally
    writeln('I absolutely need this'); // this line will execute
end;
writeln('and this'); // this line will not execute
```

In second version exception will be handled by `except` block and code following will continue with normal execution.

```
try
  StrToInt('AA'); // if this code throws exception and it will
except
end;
writeln('I absolutely need this'); // this line will execute
writeln('and this'); // this line will also execute
```

---

In linked question you have nested exception blocks, and that situation will behave differently than above one, in the way it was explained in answers to that question.

---

Documentation: [Delphi Exceptions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Exceptions)

Comment: Haven't seen that in documentation. So, in a `try..finally` block, the control jumps out of the function when `finally` ends, **if* and only *if* an exception is raised during `try`. Thanks for clearing this.

Comment: You mean this? "If an exception is raised but not handled in the finally clause, **that exception** is propagated out of the try...finally statement...". I hope this discussion is not a result of my bad English!

Comment: *" ... once statementList2 finishes executing, the exception is re-raised. "*

Comment: Reading and understanding are two different things. Especially, if English is not your native language. Obvious things may be not so obvious.

Comment: IRL  try...finally is mostly used to manage scoped allocations and has nothing to do with EH. A funny fact is that for your example, variants of StrtoInt exist: TryStrToInt, StrToIntDef, etc.

Comment: FWIW, in the second code block, the exception is not handled, just swallowed. What should IMO be stressed is that try-finally is used for resource protection, while try-except is really meant to handle the exceptions one can handle (and not just swallow them).